# How to print the text file without boxes in java?

Tags: java

I have a text file that i'm trying to print but it prints boxes in between two characters. My code works fine for all the text files except this particular one. I cannot copy-paste this box character. So that i can check if the given character is that box and not print it using if condition. Please help. Thanks

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Sometimes the box is used in place of a Unicode character that is not present in the currently selected font.  Have you tried printing in a different font, one with a wider coverage on Unicode?

Answer (score 0):

Without a sample of the text you are trying to print, I think that it might be an issue with encoding. [Here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html) is a list of encodings supported by the java language. You might then want to do something like this:

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
String s = ...;
try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(file, charset)) {
    writer.write(s, 0, s.length());
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
}
```

(Example taken from [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html).)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your document is UTF-16 encoded. Try to reencode it to UTF-8 or ASCII.